# How to filter body content in an Azure Logical Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My basic workflow is this: I check an FTP server for a specific file. If the file exist, I pick up the file and sends it to a Blob Storage. My problem is this: I want to filter the file content, eg. remove first and last row since they dont contain any real data before I send it to the blob. The first row consist of a time stamp and the last row contains a "row count". The file contains comma separated fields. How do I accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Thanks
Ausgar

Comment: Could you please tell me what extension this file is.

Comment: Do you mean type of file? In that case it´s a CSV file.

Comment: Could you please give me a brief example of the contents of the file.

Comment: File looks like this:
8/18/2020 8:00:26 AM
324432432,4324324,4324,234324,432432432,fdsfdsf432432
432545435,5435435,5435435,5435435,543543543,fsfdsfdsf,dasdasd
ROWCOUNT: 8422

Comment: Any ideas Frank? Did my file example make any sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple solution for this problem. You can try converting [csv to json](https://github.com/logicappsio/CSVtoJSON), delete unnecessary data from it, and create a blob based on that json, but this is sounds harder than it should be.

Consider using [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview):

> Azure Functions allows you to run small pieces of code (called
> "functions") without worrying about application infrastructure. With
> Azure Functions, the cloud infrastructure provides all the up-to-date
> servers you need to keep your application running at scale.

It will be much easier to do such file manipulation there.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I will handle the filtering/conversion in a Function instead. Thanks!